# How to package MSMQ (or similar) server into an application?

Tags: c#, embed, message-queue

I'm putting together an application that is intended to install copies of itself in a downstream server(s). I've been reading about RabbitMQ, and am very interested in using message queueing when the upstream/downstream applications talk to each other. From what I can tell with both RabbitMQ and MSMQ, the server/broker component needs to be installed first either from an installer or a script. I'd like to use a NuGet package or similar so the upstream application can remotely install a copy of itself downstream without having someone (or a script) install the prerequisite, as this is meant to be unattended all the time.

My question - is there a message queueing library available where I can embed it into my application for both the client and server components of MQ?

The idea is to do something like this (psuedo-code):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyQueueServer.Start();
        MyQueueServer.MessageReceived += FancyCallback;
    }

    static void FancyCallback(object sender, CustomEventArgs e)
    {
        ReadMessageAndDoStuff(e);
    }

    static void SendMessage()
    {
        string message = "hello server";
        var sender = new MyQueueClient(serverConfigDetails);
        sender.Send(message);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Looks like ZeroMQ may be the way to go, but it looks like I'm missing out on durability bit by persisting stuff to disk. I'm also unclear if ZeroMQ will keep trying to deliver a message if the remote host is offline. The Google says you need to roll your own implementation for these kinds of things. I'm willing to do this, but still hopeful for a different solution that I can take advantage of.

Comment: Come on guys, stop flagging this for closing. It's a very specific question: a message hub which is embed-able and has durability features. Not too many of those around.